# Getting all mailto links with jQuery

Tags: jquery, pattern-matching, mailto

I need a pattern that will traverse the document and get me all links that have mailto in their href:

```
<a href="mailto:an@email.com">text</a>
```

I could of course easily get all `a` elements (`$("a")`) and check each `href` attribute to see if it points to a mailto but I think that jQuery has some form of pattern matching that will allow me to do just that.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]')
```

Double quotes are usually redundant, but needed in this special case, because `:` would otherwise be interpreted as the start of a pseudo-selector. So `$('a[href^=mailto]')` would also work, but in this particular scenario, the quotes are probably a neater way to go.

Comment: I'm getting an error unless I wrap `mailto` in double quotes, like this `$('a[href^="mailto:"]');`

Comment: @tmslnz: Good catch! It's the `:` that necessitates the quotes. Updated.

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma: That's not very informative. [The code works](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbRPj/). Something is wrong with your markup, your jQuery, your selector, the time and/or scope of execution, or in how you treat the result. Seeing as OP considered this answer to answer the question, you may be better off creating a new question, if this answer doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @David I am sorry. The code is working. I was having a conflict with prototype